# AngularJS data binding not showing german umlaut characters

Tags: angularjs

I want to display German JSON data in AngularJS, but the German umlauts like "Ü" are displayed as "Ãœber". Here is a test file:
https://gist.github.com/ngeorgiev/6318718

How can I fix that?

Comment: try use 1.1.5 and create issue here https://github.com/angular/angular.js

Comment: Did you try to set encoding in the html document `<meta charset="utf-8">`?

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"> was the solution! Thanks!